# Addition going wrong in Python

Tags: python

I am a beginner at python and am writing a basic calculator

```
while True:
    print("PyCalc")
    print()
    print()
    init=input("Press 1 for Basic arithmetic")
    if init=="1":
        input1=input("Basic Arithmetic...Only +,-,*,/ accepted...")
        input2=re.findall(r'\d+|\+|\-|\*|\/',input1 )
        ans =basiccalc(input2)
        print(ans )
```

The method basiccalc:

```
def basiccalc(givenlist):
    ans=int(givenlist[0])
    for pt in givenlist:
        if str(pt).isdigit():
            continue
        elif pt=='+':
            pos=givenlist.index(pt)
            ans=ans+int(givenlist[pos+1])

return ans
```

when I run the program...adding 2 numbers works correctly.

```
  PyCalc


  Press 1 for Basic arithmetic1
  Basic Arithmetic...Only +,-,*,/ accepted...2+3
  5
```

but when I enter more than 2 numbers...it gives me a wrong answer

```
PyCalc


Press 1 for Basic arithmetic1
Basic Arithmetic...Only +,-,*,/ accepted...2+4+5+6
14
```

why do I get such an answer?

Comment: Hint: `"2+4+5+6".index("+")` will only ever return `1`.

Answer (score 0):

First problem you must use raw_input function instead of input, because input already compute arithmetique operation on input.

Second problem is in your basiccalc function for more than 2 number the last one was not calculate, try that:

```
import re

def sum(a,b):
    return a+b


def basiccalc(givenlist):
    ans=0
    op=sum
    for pt in givenlist:
        if str(pt).isdigit():
            ans = op(ans,int(pt))
            last = int(pt)
        elif pt=='+':
            op=sum
    return ans            

input1=raw_input("Basic Arithmetic...Only +,-,*,/ accepted...")
input2 = re.findall( r'\d+|\+|\-|\*|\/', input1 )
ans = basiccalc(input2)
print(ans)
```

For more information about parsing look at Dragon Book code example :
https://github.com/lu1s/dragon-book-source-code/blob/master/parser/Parser.java